Monitor Going To Sleep Wakes Other Screens
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 with a set of three Sceptre monitors.  I'm running into an issue after Screen Blank activates. After idle, the screens will correctly go blank and start to go into standby mode, but immediately wake back up afterward.  I believe this has to do with them trying to auto-switch to another input, which then registers them as being disconnected.  Unfortunately the monitors have no setting to disable auto source select, so I'm stuck looking for another option.
How can I modify the behavior or entirely disable automatic detection of the monitor configuration?  I never change the configuration, and don't mind having to run a command on the chance that it does need to be changed.
